# UI does not move when the window is resized

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Somehow, and I can't get why, some parts of my UI don't move when I resize the window. It looks like they are not placed relative to the canvas borders, even though they are children of the Canvas. I tried to unparent and re-parent my UI components having this issue but nothing solves it. I restarted unity, deleted these parts and created them again adding new UI objects, and still the very same issue. While my older parts of the UI nicely resize with the canvas. 
Do you have any idea of what could go wrong ?

before resizing the window:
[image]

after resizing the window using the mouse:
[image]

The white square is supposed to stay in the top left hand corner but just seems like fixed.

Comment: It is almost impossible to help you without picture of your problem. Also, put the code you are using to resize the UI in your question.

Comment: I have just added some pictures for more clarity.

Comment: Ok, so put the code you use to resize it.

Comment: I'm not using any code, I'm just resizing the window using the mouse like any other window

Comment: I'm just using Unity's IDE to place these components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the pivots of your UI components from the transform component theres is a box click on it and press shift and alt to set a pivot . Also use a panel as parent for components you need to resize .